# Handling Multiple Button Clicks On a Dialog

Tags: button, onclick

I have a custom dialog and many (at least 40) buttons works differently. I know how to make them workable by setting onClickListener to each. Thus I wish to shortening the code. How can I achieve that. Thanks

Comment: Add your code so we can help you shorten it.

Comment: I created a private method and call it within the the dialog every time and here is the private method. Below in the answer column.